# Make "walls" follow canvas edge (Matter.js)

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I have set up this Matter.js scene that has three walls - **ground**, **wall left** and **wall right**. Initially their positions are set so that they are exactly on their designated edges of the scene.

This is the code for defining the scene with the walls:

```
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
            Render = Matter.Render,
            World = Matter.World,
            Bodies = Matter.Bodies;
        var engine = Engine.create();
        var container = $(this).get()[0];
        var canvas = $(this).find("canvas").get()[0];
        var render = Render.create({
            element: container,
            canvas: canvas,
            engine: engine,
            options: {
                width: container.offsetWidth,
                height: container.offsetHeight,
                wireframes: false,
            }
        });

        canvas.width = container.offsetWidth;
        canvas.height = container.offsetHeight;

window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    canvas.width = container.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = container.offsetHeight
});

        // create two boxes and a ground
var ground = Bodies.rectangle(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height + 30, canvas.width, 60, {
    isStatic: true, label: "Ground"
});
var wallLeft = Bodies.rectangle(-30, canvas.height / 2, 60, canvas.height, {
    isStatic: true, label: "Wall Left"
});
var wallRight = Bodies.rectangle(canvas.width + 30, canvas.height / 2, 60, canvas.height, {
    isStatic: true, label: "Wall Right"
});
```

What I'm looking for is a way to change the position of the walls on `window.resize`. So basically just assign the same size properties again on the bodies when the window is resized. How would I do this? Could I in some way change the position of the walls by getting them by their labels and then just change the `position.x` and `position.y` values? If so, how do I select a specific body by its label?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just figured out that you can use the declared variables for each of the walls in order to select them. So the following code works in terms of changing the position of the walls:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    canvas.width = container.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = container.offsetHeight
    Matter.Body.setPosition(ground, {x: canvas.width / 2, y: canvas.height + 30})
    Matter.Body.setPosition(wallRight, {x: canvas.width + 30, y: canvas.height / 2})
});
```

However, I still need to change the width of the `ground` wall according to the `container.offsetWidth`. But it seems like the only way to change the width of an already created body is to scale it. Please reach out in the comments if you know a way to change the width of a body in pixels instead of scaling it.

Comment: You can set the width of a body with `Matter.Body.scale` using some math. All you need is a variable storing the previous width of the canvas. Then, you would do `Matter.Body.scale(ground, canvas.width/prevWidth, 1)` and update `prevWidth` to be the current width of the canvas.